# How to use directive scope variable in template html attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use the scope variable in template:

```
function FruitDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      name: '@'
    },
    template: `
    {{name}}
    <span name="name"></span>
    `
  };
}
```

For example, the `name="Apple"`

The first code `{{name}}` can directly appear `Apple`

The second code `<span fruit-name="name"></span>`, I want to parse to `<span name="Apple"></span>`, But it's not work.

So how to correctly using it? Thanks. It's better if you can give me the source of the concept. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything.

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5196/

I want the result to be `Hello, AppleApple`

Comment: did you try `name="{{name}}"`?  `name` is a standard HTML attribute, it is not an angular directive, and therefore it can't interpolate the variable into a string on it's own.

Comment: @Claies Sorry I just give a example, didn't notice that. just thought as `fruit-name="{{name}}"`

Comment: right, that would get the variable into the directive, but you want the value of `name` to be passed to the `name` property of the `span`, essentially in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('fruitDirective', function() {
  
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      name: '=fruit'
    },
    template: `
    {{name}}
    <span name="{{name}}"></span>
    `
  };  

});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  // controller
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello,
    <fruit-directive fruit="'Apple'"></fruit-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, I think the double quote is not require? cos the apple is already a string, we just put `fruit-name=name` is working

Comment: Where you gonna put `fruit-name=name` in directive call or implementtion? Or you are planning to pass `name` from ctrl.

Comment: @Stephen are you suggesting something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/Lvc0u55v/5110/

Answer (score 0):

Use {{name}} for setting the attribute as well.

```
template: `
<span name="{{name}}">fruit: {{name}}</span>
`
```

Also your template must return a single root element, so I think putting the {{name}} outside of the  element may have caused an error.

Here is a jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/h9f62jmw/1/